# Can I use .dll in Angular2 Typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript, dll

My client have .dll library and want a native angular2 app with algorithm from this library. So here is a question can i import .dll into angular2 project written in typescript. If i can't what kind of libraries can i import into Typescript.

Comment: What kind of library is it? Business logic algorithms? Is it not possible to use that on your server side and back to your client side via angular? I don't see why you want any critical  business logics on your client side.

Comment: Yes, we know that, but client really insisted on offline implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can however install any javascript libraries, which are usually hosted on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). There are thousands of them, therefore I doubt you will problem finding what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check those two NPM packages:

- [edge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edge)
- [winax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax)